# Infinite recursive function -> Stack Overflow error

Tags: java, recursion, netbeans, stack, stack-overflow

I have an infinite recursive loop in java

```
public  void infiniteLoop(Long x){

    System.out.println(""+x);
    infiniteLoop(x + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StackOverFlow st = new StackOverFlow();
    st.infiniteLoop(0L); 
}
```

In this piece of code it display an StackOverFlow error as expected, but if I look in the console output the error is displayed in multiple lines:

```
4806
4807
4808
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
    at stackoverflow.StackOverFlow.infiniteLoop(StackOverFlow.java:234809
)
    at stackoverflow.StackOverFlow.infiniteLoop(StackOverFlow.java:24)
    at stackoverflow.StackOverFlow.infiniteLoop(StackOverFlow.java:24)
4810
4811
4812
```

My question is, why does this happens? shouldn't it stops as soon as the first Stack Overflow error is displayed?

Comment: Probably buffering the `stdout`, and printing what's in `stderr` as soon as it arrives, and then flushing the `stdout` after the crash.

Comment: That's because the error is written to `stderr` whereas the output is written to `stdout`. Those may not synchronize very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [S]houldn't it stops as soon as the first Stack Overflow error is displayed?

Actually the program stops at the *first stackoverflow exception*. But **exceptions are written to the `stderr` channel** (so `System.err.println(..)`) whereas you print output to the `stdout` channel.

The terminal listens to both channels and aims to print them in a good way, but since these are separate channels, there is *no* guarantee that the order in which the producers write to the channels is displayed correctly: the order of the individual channels is always correct, but if data is written to both channels (almost) concurrently, the streams might be mixed up a bit.

You can alter your program to print to the `stderr` as well:

```
public void infiniteLoop(Long x){
    System.err.println(""+x); // error channel.
    infiniteLoop(x + 1);
}
```

Now the order in which data is written to the channel should also be the order in which it is displayed on the terminal.